# Multithreading in Python with the threading and queue modules

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file with hundreds of thousands of lines, each line of which needs to be undergo the same process (calculating a co-variance). I was going to multithread because it takes pretty long as is. All the examples/tutorials I have seen have been fairly complicated for what I want to do, however. If anyone could point me to a good tutorial that explains how to use the two modules together that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have to process something in parallel, I use something similar to this (I just ripped this out of an existing script):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

import os, sys, time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Manager, Process, Value, Event, cpu_count

class ThreadedProcessor(object):
  def __init__(self, parser, input_file, output_file, threads=cpu_count()):
    self.parser = parser

    self.num_processes = threads
    self.input_file = input_file
    self.output_file = output_file

    self.shared_proxy = Manager()

    self.input_queue = Queue()
    self.output_queue = Queue()

    self.input_process = Process(target=self.parse_input)
    self.output_process = Process(target=self.write_output)

    self.processes = [Process(target=self.process_row) for i in range(self.num_processes)]

    self.input_process.start()
    self.output_process.start()

    for process in self.processes:
      process.start()

    self.input_process.join()

    for process in self.processes:
      process.join()

    self.output_process.join()

  def parse_input(self):
    for index, row in enumerate(self.input_file):
      self.input_queue.put([index, row])

    for i in range(self.num_processes):
      self.input_queue.put('STOP')

  def process_row(self):
    for index, row in iter(self.input_queue.get, 'STOP'):
      self.output_queue.put([index, row[0], self.parser.parse(row[1])])

    self.output_queue.put('STOP')

  def write_output(self):
    current = 0
    buffer = {}

    for works in range(self.num_processes):
      for index, id, row in iter(self.output_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        if index != current:
          buffer[index] = [id] + row
        else:
          self.output_file.writerow([id] + row)
          current += 1

          while current in buffer:
            self.output_file.writerow(buffer[current])
            del buffer[current]
            current += 1
```

Basically, you have two processes managing the reading/writing of the file. One reads and parses the input, the other reads from the "done" queue and writes to your output file. The other processes are spawned (in this case the number is equal to the number of total processor cores your CPU has) and they all process elements from the input queue.